# Problems with floating arithmetic in bash

Tags: command-line, bash

I have code in bash:

```
a=$(cat "tempf.out")
```

Where tempf.out is smth like this:

```
-432.4319347412
```

I want to multyiply it by 2, so, I write:

```
result=$(expr $a*2)
```

But I get this:

```
*232.4319347412
```

If I try to use bc:

```
result=$(expr $a*2|bc)
```

I get:

```
(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^M
```

Please, help to fix it.

Comment: Whats the output of `echo $a`?

Comment: It gives -432.4319347412

Comment: Whats the output of `expr $a*2`?

Comment: `result=$(expr $a*2|bc -l)` should fix it.  `-l` means mathlib routines.

Comment: @Terrance It should work as is right now..

Comment: @heemayl Yeah, you are correct.  Something must be wrong with his input then. I tested both ways and they worked fine.  =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `tempf.out` file has DOS-style line endings (CR-LF) then you will need to fix that - either at the file level using `dos2unix`, `tr`, or `sed` for example, e.g.

```
a=$(sed 's/\r$//' tempf.out)
bc <<< "$a*2"
```

or by removing it from the `$a` variable using the shell's parameter substitution capabilities e.g.

```
a=$(<tempf.out)
bc <<< "${a%^M}*2"
```

where the `^M` is an actual carriage return composed using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>

Comment: tempf.out is produced by commad echo $line | sed -e "s/^.\{4\}//">tempf.out     Is it smth wrong with this code?

Comment: I'd suggest `a=$(sed 's/\r$//' tempf.out)` if you want to go the sed route

Answer (score -1):

Thanks a lot for everybody

```
a=$(sed 's/\r$//' tempf.out)
result=$(expr $a*2 | bc)    
echo $result
```

works for me

Comment: `expr` is not doing anything for you there (it needs whitespace around the operators, and only handles integers anyway): may as well replace with `echo`

Comment: This is a duplicate of steeldriver's answer.